# UITableView changes scroll position when cell height changes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `tableView` that expands cell height when user taps on cell. The problem is in some cells after expanding cell height `tableView` scrolls very higher or lower the `selectedCell` I mean it miss the current cell position

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if cellsMode[indexPath.row] {
        return 344
    }
else {
        return 140 }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    self.cellsMode[indexPath.row] = !self.cellsMode[indexPath.row] 
    table.reloadData() 
}
```

I tried to use

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: cellInex, section: 0)
self.table.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
```

but it not worked.
How can i fixed it?

Comment: please add code for 'when user taps on cell'

Comment: @SPatel I set a flag in didSelectForrowat func to true or false and then reloadData  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.cellsMode[indexPath.row] = !self.cellsMode[indexPath.row]
        table.reloadData()
    }

Comment: @SPatel thanks.It solved that problem but in some cases the cell ccloses before expanding.I set the animated to none but it not work.

Comment: i think it may be due to your constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reload cell not entire tableview, like bellow:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    self.cellsMode[indexPath.row] = !self.cellsMode[indexPath.row] 
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```